# What are the recent changes to the AK74U?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Looking at the [latest patch for BLOPs](http://www.callofduty.com/board/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=313362), there seems to be a a reference to adjustments made to the AK74U - can anyone shed some light on what these adjustments are?

Answer (score 3):

**Patch 1.06**

From what I can find there seemed to be a significant accuracy advantage over using the AK-74u (even without a grip).  They increased the amount of vertical recoil to the gun. The general consensus on the forums is the gun is still very strong despite the nerfs.

Answer (score 2):

They lowered the additional **center speed** that the **grip attachment** gave it from 200 to 100.

Higher center speed means faster recovery as well as dampening the recoil.